# how to show inputbox while hover some element in Vuejs 2.0

Tags: vue.js, inline-editing

I'm new to Vuejs environment.I have to implement inline editing in Vuejs.Initially there will be paragraph.
While mouseover i want to show the textbox in the same position and hide the paragraph element and vice versa.

How to achieve this in Vuejs?

Comment: Please go through: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of what I think you are asking for. 
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ueQop0?p=preview)

```
<body>
<div id="app">
    <p @mouseover="mouseOver" v-show="!active"> {{message}}</p>
    <div v-show="active" @mouseleave="mouseOut">
    <input v-model="message" placeholder="edit me">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
 new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                message: "Message can be shown here",
                active:false,
            },
            methods: {
                mouseOver: function(){
                    this.active = true;   

                },
                mouseOut:function(){
                this.active=false;
                }
            } 
});</script></body>
```

P.S. please share what you have done while asking question on stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you .But i need to implement for list of items.